# How to detect ViewDidDisappear from parent view controller in IOS

Tags: ios, swift

I know I can override `ViewDidDisappear` in a view controller to detect when it is called from inside itself but if I want a function to be called in the parent controller, it's not clean as I need to call differently depending on the parent class.
I think I read somewhere that it is possible to add listeners to detect that from within the parent but I can't find it again.
Can someone help?

Comment: In fact I could validate your answer but it seems simpler to do from child by checking parent type and doing the appropriate action, also because I need to convert to c# and it's too hard for me...

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways to go about this. One possibility would be to create a delegate protocol on your `ChildViewController`.

```
protocol ChildViewControllerDelegate: class {
  func notifyParent(sender: ChildViewController)
}
```

You would also create a `delegate` var on your `ChildViewController`, like so:

```
  weak var delegate: ChildViewControllerDelegate?
```

On your `ParentViewController`, you'd segue to it as follows:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "MySegue", sender: self)
```

In your `prepareForSegue`, you'd have something like this:

```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "MySegue" {
      let destinationViewController = segue.destination as! ChildViewController
      destinationViewController.delegate = self

    }
  }
```

Also on `ParentViewController`, you'd implement the protocol, as follows:

```
extension ParentViewController: ChildViewControllerDelegate {
  func notifyParent(sender: ChildViewController) {
    print("Do Whatcha Gotta Do")
  }
}
```

Then, whenever you dismiss `ChildViewController`, just call the delegate method in the completion block of `dismiss`, like so:

```
dismiss(animated: true) {
  self.delegate?.notifyParent(sender: self)
}
```

As an example, you could have the dismiss code inside of an `IBAction`, like so:

```
  @IBAction func closeButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    dismiss(animated: true) {
      self.delegate?.notifyParent(sender: self)
    }
  }
```

...or if you're dismissing the `ChildViewController` another way, you could just implement `viewDidDisappear`, as follows:

```
  override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(true)
    delegate?.notifyParent(sender: self)
  }
```